# Using LD_PRELOAD with Apache Spark (or YARN)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ld-preload

We are running Spark jobs on Apache Hadoop YARN. I have a special need to use the "LD_PRELOAD trick" on these jobs. *(Before anyone panics, it's not for production runs; this is part of automated job testing).*

I know how to submit additional files with the job, and I know how to set environment variables on the nodes, so adding these settings to `spark-defaults.conf` almost provides a solution:

```
spark.files=/home/todd/pwn_connect.so
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_PRELOAD=pwn_connect.so
spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD=pwn_connect.so
```

But I get this error in the container logs:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'pwn_connect.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

The problem seems to be that LD_PRELOAD doesn't accept the relative path that I'm providing. But I don't know how to provide an absolute path -- I don't have a clue where on the local filesystem of the nodes these files are being placed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `spark.files` is not used when running on YARN, it should be `spark.yarn.dist.files`. And note that this will be overwritten if the `--files` argument is provided to `spark-submit`.

For LD_PRELOAD, there are two solutions that will work:

1. Relative paths *can* be used; they need to be prefixed with `./`:

   ```
   spark.yarn.dist.files=/home/todd/pwn_connect.so
   spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_PRELOAD=./pwn_connect.so
   spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD=./pwn_connect.so
   ```

   (relative paths without `./` are searched for in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, rather than the current working directory).
2. If an absolute path is preferred, examining the [Spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/Client.scala) reveals that the whole command line including environment variable assignments are subject to expansion by the shell, so the expression `$PWD` will be expanded to the current working directory:

   ```
   spark.yarn.dist.files=/home/todd/pwn_connect.so
   spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/pwn_connect.so
   spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/pwn_connect.so
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem for a year and half，tried several ways, did not worked； until I saw this comment. Thank you.

```
--conf spark.yarn.dist.files=/usr/lib64/libopenblas64.so \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LD_PRELOAD=./libopenblas64.so \
--conf spark.executorEnv.LD_PRELOAD=./libopenblas64.so \
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34677583)